# Excluir perfil/vínculo com uma "comunidade" específica

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, contas-usuário

Não estou querendo remover a conta toda (como neste link [How do I delete my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)), apenas de uma comunidade específica.

É possível remover este vínculo?

Comment: Nãããããããão! Não deixe a gente ;_;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agora (creio que desde [*Agosto deste ano [2017]*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300185/198279)) é possível remover o perfil se desejar da comunidade especifica a qualquer momento, basta ir no seu perfil, clicando na foto no topo:

> [image: perfil]

Depois clicar em `Editar Perfil`:

> [image: editar perfil]

Vai notar no meu lateral a opção `Excluir perfil`:

> [image: Excluir perfil]

Selecione o checkbox para habilitar o botão <kbd>Remover Perfil</kbd> (**Note** que este processo é **irreversível**), clicando no botão o processo será iniciado.

> [image: remover perfil]

Comment: Olá Guilherme, esse botão de exclusão não aparece no meu perfil. Porque ? Eu gostaria de excluir toda a minha conta!

Answer (score 12):

Aqueles procedimentos dizem:

- Se você nunca votou ou publicou *naquela comunidade*, pode excluir a conta sozinho pelo link que tem no seu perfil.
- Caso contrário, você deve usar o [formulário de contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) para entrar em contato direto com os administradores do site. Lá tem um campo de descrição onde você pode explicar o que quer. Se fizer isso pelo nosso site, pode escrever em português.

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto sua resposta deixou bem claro +1, por enquanto irei refletir sobre se decido ou não efetuar o procedimento, mais uma vez muito obrigado.