# Por que no stack overflow em português tudo é tão mais negativado?

Tags: debate

Não me considero um membro ativo da comunidade, mas fico intrigado com a quantidade de respostas negativadas o SO em português tem em comparação ao SO normal. Só de abrir a página inicial já dá pra ver a diferença gigantesca.

**Vocês não acham que a função de downvote vem sido usada de maneira errada ou com exageros no site?** Um -1 sem um comentário justificando não traz nada de positivo a uma pergunta (Quando em uma resposta pode ser para dizer que a resposta está errada ou ruim, para outros usuários não confiarem nela, etc). A pergunta continuará ruim e o autor, juntamente com outras pessoas que visita.

### Muitas vezes serve como um desmotivador, vou contar uma experiência própria minha:

Dei uma resposta e citei um link de referência. Recebi um -1 e um comentário me explicando o porquê de não usar links da maneira que usei <strike>do usuário mais maneiro da comunidade</strike>. Pensei: Opa, beleza, não vou mais fazer isso, deixa eu editar a resposta aqui, sendo o -1 usada de maneira correta.

Vou contar como é uma experiência negativa agora:
Após pesquisar a internet toda, tentando várias soluções para meu problema, resolvo postar uma pergunta no stack overflow. Leio sobre como fazer uma pergunta, tento descrever claramente minha dúvida criando um *"exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável"*. Após dar uma revisada, posto então minha questão. Para ter mais chances de obter uma resposta, posto tanto no SO quanto no SO em português.
Passam-se os minutos e vou checar se tive alguma resposta. Abro o SO e vejo um comentário útil, dando uma dica sobre como encontrar meu erro. Abro o SO em português e encontro um -1. Não sei a razão, não sei o que melhorar, só sei que alguém não gostou da minha pergunta. **No que isso me ajuda?**

Comment: Leia: [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%c3%83o-%c3%89-o-stackoverflow-com) e [Votos negativos sem legitimidade?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6705/137387)

Comment: Relacionado: [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/112052)

Comment: Caso Vitor, isso já foi debatido muitas vezes, faça uma busca, leia tudo se tiver realmente interesse em entender o que são e como funcionam os votos, e o porque provavelmente tomou alguns downvotes https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=votos+negativos --- esse assunto é praticamente duplicata de tão debatido que já foi.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8047/101

Comment: **"No que isso me ajuda?"** Justamente. O site não é para ajudar **só você** (aqui sequer é um site de ajuda), é para fornecer **para a comunidade toda** o melhor conteúdo possível, classificado conforme o mérito de cada postagem. Recentemente foi elaborado um guia bem completo que ajuda a entender os principais problemas a serem evitados nas postagens (em especial, perguntas) mas que ajuda a entender praticamente toda a base do site: [Guia de Sobrevivência do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70) - Ele pode fazer toda a diferença no aproveitamento do potencial do site.

Comment: Quando a pessoa faz uma pergunta ruim e fica desmotivada a fazer outra o sistema funcionou bem.

Comment: se vc acompanhar o SO em inglês, talvez vc não veja tantas negativas pq na verdade lá a velocidade que as perguntas são fechadas e somem da lista é espantosa... não pense que não acontece lá... eu estava uma vez comentando uma pergunta e em uns 2min em q eu escrevia um comentário a pergunta teve -7 votes e foi fechada pra ter uma ideia... e como já comentaram, lá é lá, cá é cá, são sites diferentes... e se as pessoas lessem o guia de sobrevivência talvez muitas dessas perguntas não seriam negativadas, talvez a questão seja "por que não entender como funciona antes de usar?" ;)

Comment: Eu não queria entrar na minha questão em si pq parece butthurt, mas aí que tá. Recebi um -1 aqui e não lá. Elaborei a pergunta de modo que o erro ficasse claramente explícito e reproduzível, falei o que tentei antes, mostrei até o output.
Recebi um -1 de graça. "Quando uma pessoa faz uma pergunta ruim e fica desmotivada". A pergunta não foi ruim, e eu fiquei desmotivado foi a elaborar uma pergunta boa, porque se eu tivesse feito uma pergunta podre ia dar no mesmo, já que não recebi ajuda nenhuma e ainda ganhei um -1 de brinde.

Comment: @VitorCeolin você sequer mostrou que pergunta é, e o tempo todo está falando da sua pergunta. Se ela fosse tão boa porque não postou para as pessoas fazerem a avaliação? Você pode achar boa mas outras pessoas podem não achar. Só a sua opinião que conta? Em geral a pessoa que faz a pergunta é q que menos tem condição de avaliar se ela é boa ou não. Sem falar que ela será tendenciosa por natureza, que é diferente e adicional a ela não ser o conhecimento necessário sobre o assunto e sobre o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Inclusive o @RicardoPontual apontou bem um erro de avaliação que você fez querendo comparar com outro site que você nem consegue ver o que acontece lá e o que ele diz vive acontecendo, quase tudo que é ruim lá some muito rápido. Se você fez essa avaliação errada por que acha que a avaliação que a sua pergunta está boa não está errada também? Já foi passado *links* para você ver como fazer uma pergunta boa e porque esse tipo de crítica não levará a lugar algum.

Comment: Faz sentido o que você falou, não quis postar minha pergunta pq quis falar sobre o tema e não sobre ela. Falei sobre ela porque é um caso que contraria o que o pessoal falou, só isso. mas já que acabei entrando demais nela, agradeceria um feedback pra melhorar da próxima https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439773/metodo-de-post-recebendo-o-viewmodel-como-null

Comment: Eu não sei se leu. E se leu não sei se compreendeu. E se compreendeu não sei porque insiste no mesmo argumento que já não deveria existir mais depois depois de ter essas novas informações, poderia ter outros argumentos, embora ninguém até hoje conseguiu ter um que resolva o problema. No fim é sempre a pessoa querendo que a pergunta dela seja melhor aceita sem se preocupar com outras consequências, é a pessoa querendo que o site aceite qualquer coisa. E mesmo que tido isso seja errado e o negativo seja errado, é algo que acontece.

Comment: Eu recebo negativo quase todo dia como retaliação porque fecho perguntas ou contrario interesses. Infelizmente não o mundo é cheio de pessoas sem critério, e diminuir o critério não é uma solução que fará algo evoluir. Lembrando que o site deve ajudar muitas pessoas e não uma pessoa individualmente, por isso ele é um Q&A e não um helpdesk que alguns chama de fórum, e até isso é o termo errado para o que as pessoas querem. De resto tudo já foi discutido, você não está colocando luz nova no problema, então estamos todos perdendo tempo.

Comment: Pra mim a pergunta beira a ampla ou não clara, quem sabe talvez até fora de escopo mas como eu não tenho certeza eu prefiro não fazer nada. aparentemente a do SOen é https://stackoverflow.com/q/60456121/221800. Também não foi bem recebida e continua sem uma resposta, porque é difícil responder esse tip ode coisa. Ou não dá com essas informações ou dá muito trabalho para a pessoa ajudar você em algo muito específico seu. A pergunta ficará lá largada se não estiver negativada e não ajudará qualquer pessoa (o objetivo do site é ajudar muitos). **O que a pessoa que vai te ajudar ganha com isso?**

Comment: @VitorCeolin não vi sua pergunta e não vou entrar no mérito se estava boa ou não, e peço que não desanime por isso,  mas vou citar uma coisa... há 1 ano e meio atrás ou pouco mais a qualidade aqui estava bem ruim, cheio de perguntas com todos os problemas possíveis para serem fechadas, eu inclusive estava desanimado com isso... a comunidade e os moderadores de uns tempos pra cá tem feito um bom trabalho em avaliar as perguntas e fechar as que não estão de acordo com os critérios.. de novo, não sei sobre a sua pergunta, mas prefiro como está mais criterioso agora do que era há uns tempos atrás

Comment: @RicardoPontual não faço questão que vejam iminha pergunta, por isso não coloquei no post. Só coloquei porque insistiram. 
Minha pergunta não beira ampla, ela é extremamente específica. Tem toda a informação necessária e sem nenhuma desnecessária. A pessoa que me ajudar ganha pontinhos de mentirinha em um site, o que é literalmente a motivação de 90% das pessoas que respondem perguntas aqui. Se você é negativado por retaliação não quer dizer que negativar sem motivo continua sendo certo. Sinceramente, esse foi o argumento mais patético colocado aqui

Comment: Mas qual é a reclamação, pois com a mesma pergunta você tomou negativo aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/439773/metodo-de-post-recebendo-o-viewmodel-como-null e também tomou negativo no SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456121/viewmodel-returning-null-on-post-method.

Comment: Detalhe, no SO sua pergunta em 15 dias teve apenas 28 leitura o que para o padrão de movimentação deles e ínfimo, para eles um número de 500 leituras nesse mesmo período é considerado baixo. enquanto aqui você publicou ela ontem e já obteve 32 leituras num dia ou seja tiveram mais apreço a sua pergunta por aqui do que por lá.

Comment: @VitorCeolin sua pergunta beira a ampla e o fato de você insistir nisso mostra que seu critério não bate com o da comunidade. Não tem nada de específico nela, e parece que não leu o que foi recomendado para você. E assim não irá melhorar nada. E acho que isso responde o que perguntou. è desgastante. Você comenta, passa instruções e a pessoa diz que tá tudo certo com a pergunta dela e não melhora nada. A grande maioria dos casos é assim, ela acha que está certa e nada muda, por isso as pessoas **desanimaram em comentar e só negativam**.O desânimo nasceu de não ser efetivo.

Comment: É pior ainda você achar que eu disse que é certo negativar sem motivo, foi justamente o oposto do que eu disse. Eu disse que negativar com motivo é a única forma que deve acontecer. O fato de você distorcer o que eu disse mostra que sua interpretação das coisas é problemática e não vamos chegar a lugar algum, e por isso eu nem gosto de perder tempo com essas coisas, nunca chega a algum lugar, pelo menos na hora, já vi um ou outro caso depois que a pessoa ganhou experiência no site que mudou de opinião, porque ela começa falar com propriedade e não com sua vontade.

Comment: E resolvi fechar como ampla, ainda que poderia ser não clara. Passa um monde de informação, eu acho que isso viola o MCVE, mas tudo bem, mas dizer que não pode ser mais simplificado que isso. Não tem uma pergunta clara ali. Tem dizendo que conseguiu uma solução em JS, mas quer uma solução em C#. Bem, querer uma solução é a definição de pergunta ampla, quando não é fora de escopo. Pedir uma solução é muito diferente de ter um problema específico e fazer uma pergunta para resolver esse problema específico.ão.

Comment: Eu fiquei no ampla, mas quase foi no não claro, não estar claro é um dos motivos de eu não saber nem qual o melhor motivo para fechar, se ficar mais claro pode ser que dê para fechar por outro motivo ou quem sabe reabrir. Como muitas pessoas não podem votar para fechar elas negativam no lugar. Não é o ideal, mas a ferramenta é falha e consigo entender a motivação.

Comment: Embora eu entenda a frustração de receber um negativo sem saber o motivo, saiba que muita gente desistiu de comentar por causa de [coisas assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQFTx.jpg) (quem tenta ajudar - e nem sempre é quem votou - acaba sendo xingado). Por isso muitos desistiram comentar na maioria dos casos - segue [link original da postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/439326/#comment849182_439838), embora provavelmente o comentário já esteja apagado por ser um xingamento. Enfim, o ideal é que todos comentassem sempre, mas infelizmente há motivos para muitos não fazerem isso

Comment: @hkotsubo esse foi levinho.

Comment: @Maniero obrigado pelo feedback. Queria saber se era possível resolver com c# pois estava aprendendo MVC, e não estava conseguindo que o mvc fizesse o trabalho sozinho, tive que usar JS para popular o view manualmente, o que não me adicionava muito se o intuito é aprender o padrão mvc :d

Comment: Você está certíssimo, meu caro. O SO-PT é uma comunidade extremamente tóxica. Estou aqui para tentar ajudar os outros e responder coisas -- e quando respondo, recebo um agradecimento de quem perguntou e downvotes da comunidade, sem nenhuma explicação do motivo do downvotes. A recompensa é moral, por ter ajudado quem realmente precisava. Mas só faço perguntas no inglês. Lidar com ego dos outros não é brincadeira.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, eu venho acompanhando as suas publicações e vejo que st;a fazendo o uso errado da plataforma. Você usa o SOPT como se fosse um misto de fórum com helpdesk e Stack Overflow foi criado justamente para ser uma alternativa na contra mão dessas ferramentas onde ao invés de ajudar um único usuário com seu problema super especifico onde uma eventual resposta apenas o vai ajudar o usuário cria uma pergunta pontual e indexável mas não tão específica cujo as respostas além de ajudar possam ajudar milhões de outros usuários ao longo do tempo.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez Recomendo que leia [Manifesto do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto), [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), [O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de "rede social"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/137387), [O que é o Stack Overflow?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387), [Como eu posso ajudar a comunidade? Preciso ser moderador para isso?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8437/137387), [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387)

Comment: Salve, @AugustoVasques. Eu sinto muito por você achar que eu uso o SO como rede social, mas essa sua opinião me parece equivocada. Eu sequer conhecia o nome de ninguém aqui. Conheci o seu esses dias por causa de um comentário seu quando dei um voto positivo numa resposta (e concordei com seu comentário, porque eu não tinha testado ou usado a resposta, votei positivo porque me pareceu funcional, e depois comecei a atentar para isso).

Comment: Quanto ao uso como help desk, creio que um site de perguntas e respostas é isso mesmo -- mas não individual, e sim para respostas que tenham interesse coletivo. Já percebi que muita gente quer usar o SO como Zé Moleza, colocando questões de trabalho da faculdade, e tenho tentado alertar essas pessoas nos comentários.

Comment: Mas a questão de dar downvotes sem explicação permanece. Li os links que você me mandou, e eles parecem apoiar meu pensamento. Em nenhum lugar ali fala: "desça o sarrafo sem explicar por quê". Isso é nocivo, não tem pra onde correr.

Comment: Dei algumas respostas esses dias a algumas pessoas que agradeceram, e outras que sei que são funcionais, mas alguns avaliadores deram downvotes. Quem sabe o motivo? Não tenho nem como decidir se quero continuar investindo tempo aqui ou se vale à pena ajustar meu comportamento.

Comment: Nesse meio tempo, a minha decisão foi sair do SO-PT, mas como as notificações são conjuntas, terminei aparecendo aqui de novo eventualmente. Mas nunca faço perguntas aqui, já que a comunidade não tem disposição de explicar (o que torna o comportamento do downvotes tóxico). Paciência. Tinha tudo pra ser bom. Enquanto isso, eu continuo por aqui ajudando como posso.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez Sobre votos sem comentários, está tudo explicado [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8788/112052) - Inclusive explica também como sugerir mudanças. Boa leitura :-)

Comment: Salve, @hkotsubo! Concordo com o teor do seu link plenamente. Inclusive, ele suporta o que eu sustentei aqui (e o que o Augusto me falou esses dias numa postagem). O pessoal acha que está em rede social e dá downvotes porque torceu o nariz, e não porque uma resposta não seja útil (que é o conteúdo da tooltip do downvote de resposta). As pessoas são livres pra fazê-lo, mas não deixa de ser extremamente tóxico. Eu ainda dedico tempo a responder perguntas aqui por muita vontade de ajudar, mas eventualmente essa toxicidade vai me espantar de vez do SO-PT.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez No meu entendimento, o link não suporta a ideia de que o pessoal vota porque não gosta. A **pergunta** até diz "*Seria porque as pessoas aqui são "malvadas", "mesquinhas", "tóxicas", "trolls", etc, que odeiam a tudo e todos, e não querem que os novatos se sintam bem-vindos?*", mas **na resposta é explicado que não**: "*Ao contrário da "crença popular", a maioria dos usuários aqui são gentis e querem ajudar, e não gostam de "atirar nos novatos" negativando as perguntas destes para que eles se sintam mal. (Na verdade, esse não é o propósito nem a intenção dos votos negativos!)*"

Comment: @CésarRodriguez você está só colocando uma opinião, não tem sustentação. O problema é que para debater isto precisa de fatos e de espaço para você provar que não é só sua percepção baseada em uma experiência muito pequena. E aqui não tem. Não falarei para abrir uma discussão só para isto porque já ela já foi aberta diversas vezes e nunca ninguém consegue comprovar a percepção, pelo contrário. Só o fato de usar a palavra tóxico já mostra um viés no que está falando. Pra mim tóxico é ter perguntas sem sentido e respostas que ensinam errado (simplificadamente falando pela falta de espaço).

Comment: Tudo bem, concordo com você, é melhor parar essa linha de discussão por aqui. Vou só explicar o que eu tinha querido dizer com "o link suporta o que eu sustentei". O link fala que um dos motivos para não obrigar a comentar é que as tooltips muitas vezes já deixam claro o motivo (e isso faz total sentido, na minha cabeça). A tooltip da pergunta diz pra votar se for ou não "interessante, útil ou mostrou trabalho de pesquisa". Esses termos, inclusive, são muito mais amplos, é um pouco mais fácil entender o downvote. A tooltip dos votos de resposta é bem mais específica: é se a resposta é *útil*.

Comment: A questão da rede social foi trazida pelo Augusto, que me fez perceber que eu tinha dado um upvote numa resposta alheia por simpatia, por congratulação, sem atentar para a resposta em si (era uma resposta que me parecia correta em abstrato, e que já havia recebido downvote não explicado, mas numa tecnologia que eu não tinha como saber de cabeça se estava correta ou não).

Comment: Em suma: meu argumento de rede social não tem relação com seu link, é uma mistura do seu link com a fala de um usuário mais experiente, e tudo junto que fez ver que tinha gente dando downvote sem explicação e dissociado da tooltip, e certamente fazendo isso por simpatias ou antipáticas, ou porque não queria que a pergunta fosse respondida, ou sei lá o motivo (se pessoa X julga sua ação sem expor os fundamentos ou com fundamentos claramente inválidos, te fazem tentar entender qual é, efetivamente, a motivação por trás). Em tempo, é claro que respostas que ensinem errado são algo ruim.

Comment: Então, era essa a explicação. Obrigado pela paciência!

Comment: @CésarRodriguez, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/573356/137387 .Agora teste fazer o mesmo no SO inglês e vai ver o tanto de upvotes que uma resposta sua ganhará.

Answer (score 7):

Como o @Augusto Vasques mencionou ali no comentário acima, [não temos vínculo com o Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-n%C3%83o-%C3%89-o-stackoverflow-com). Somos um site a parte. Uma comunidade, moderação e equipe separada deles, e brevemente, podemos ter outra filosofia de votos.

Nós temos um sistema que identifica *spam* de votos, como ficar votando negativo em postagens de apenas uma pessoa ([Você não vai com a minha cara?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4495/voc%C3%AA-n%C3%A3o-vai-com-a-minha-cara)) ou sair [gratuitamente distribuindo votos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/votos-negativos-sem-legitimidade/6705#6705). Isto serve para *upvote* e *downvote*.

Nós somos bem democráticos, e quando envolve democracia, o voto acaba sendo pessoal e não há como evitar isso. Nós não temos um padrão para votar, e mesmo se tivéssemos, ninguém seguiria.

Acredito que na maioria o que implica em votos é:

- **A legibilidade da postagem** - o que inclui [formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas), [códigos e erros em imagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7816/postar-mensagem-de-erro-como-imagem), indentação e [ortografia](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/qual-o-correto-procedimento-a-ser-adotado-para-corrigir-erros-de-ortografia-gra).
- **Escopo da postagem** - postagens que fazem você se perguntar do que a pessoa está falando não é uma postagem com um bom escopo. Elas devem ser objetivas e claras. [Uma pergunta simples deve receber uma resposta simples?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7763/perguntas-simples-resposta-simples)
- **Dá para tirar algum proveito disso?** - quero dizer das postagens que conseguimos considerar alguma coisa delas. Negativamente para perguntas, seriam aquelas que não conseguimos reproduzir o erro, ou que é algo que só aconteça com aquela pessoa. Para respostas, é aquela onde não tem fundamento. Ou é um comentário que não vai te ajudar em nada ou é uma opinião.

O que não está citado acima não era pra influenciar nos votos na teoria. Mas na prática, alguns votam negativamente por competição, ou por não gostar de alguém ou simplesmente não concordar com a resposta.

Quando uma resposta é moralmente incorreta, infringe alguma lei, propõe uso de gambiarras ou está errada, eu voto negativo e comento sobre isso. Eu não vou negar que as vezes até eu mesmo respondo algo errado, mas nossa comunidade normalmente comenta sobre o erro, e eu peço para corrigir então.

Aqui no Meta o voto é uma exceção: [ele tem o objetivo de expressar opinião](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1668/significado-do-voto-no-meta).

Não é legal sair fiscalizando tudo que vê por aí. O sistema identifica o que deve ser analisado e joga para a fila de análise, e vários usuários analisam a mesma postagem.

Tentamos manter um padrão entre a comunidade sobre votar, fechar, sinalizar e reeducar os membros. Nem sempre é seguido, mas temos um protocolo disto. Sobre este assunto, temos um [manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas), e um [guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta) para quem não gosta de ler).

Voltando no que disse no começo: a comunidade do SOen tem sua filosofia de votar e nós não seguimos ela aqui. Na verdade, eu vejo muita coisa que considero *errada* lá que com certeza seria fechado aqui. Eu acredito que nossa comunidade é mais engajada em manter um conteúdo de qualidade do que lá onde "tudo é aceito".

Nós não aceitamos tudo, prezamos a qualidade de conteúdo. Se algo não está legal para nossos conformes, iremos negativar, fechar ou sinalizar.

E se ver que tem alguém pegando no seu pé, **sinalize**. Sinalizações são enviadas aos moderadores e eles tem as ferramentas suficientes para lidar com estas situações.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que as pessoas costumam não entender bem a pergunta do outro, não pesquisam a fundo dando a chance de fazer outros questionamentos, (sabendo que o trabalho do programador envolve pesquisa para identificar o erro), votam negativamente, como se aquela pessoa não precisasse realmente de ajuda. Então o trabalho que estão fazendo aqui é mecânico, artificial. Não estão querendo ajudar pessoas e sim, resolver problemas técnicos. Porém por trás de algo técnico está o ser humano. Sem um cérebro por trás da máquina nada funciona. Então sim, eu acho errado o tal do -1. Toda pergunta deveria ser válida. E mesmo minhas perguntas votadas negativamente, eu trago respostas e deixo aí para outros verem. Quem sabe eu ajudo alguém.

Comment: *Eu acho que as pessoas costumam não entender bem a pergunta do outro*: É justamente ao contrário, faltam aos usuários iniciantes entenderem que o [Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) possui regras de funcionamento e que não pode querer aparecer fazendo tudo da maneira que quer e deseja. Em alguns casos é tão flagrante o desinteresse de alguns usuários, por regras, que chegam a ignorar nosso [tour](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) o que seria primeiro contato do usuário com o nosso sistema de regras e a cultura da comunidade, oferecido logo após o cadastro.

Comment: "*Toda pergunta deveria ser válida*" - embora eu concorde com isso **em determinados contextos**, aqui no Stack Overflow é diferente: existe um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e portanto [nem todo tipo de pergunta é válido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). E [existem motivos para ser assim](/a/1950/112052) **<--** leia este link, é importante para entender porque nem todo tipo de pergunta serve para o modelo do site.

Comment: *sabendo que o trabalho do programador .... pessoa não precisasse realmente de ajuda*: Um coisa importante crucial na vida de usuário do Stack Overflow é compreender que [O Stack Overflow em Português **NÃO** é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um site de perguntas e respostas e nosso [sistema de votação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) visa apenas sistema de classificação da qualidade técnica, o esforço de pesquisa e utilidade do conteúdo publicado, independente de analise emocional. Se faz uma pergunta que já possui resposta o negativo é óbvio

Comment: *Então o trabalho que estão fazendo aqui é mecânico, artificial.* Alguns diriam que é um trabalho técnico e não didático, realizado por voluntários das mais diversas areas e expertises. E sim estamos a *resolver problemas técnicos* a ajuda as pessoas é consequência da solução desses problemas técnicos. Como já dito somos um site de perguntas e respostas sobre linguagens de programação cujo o nosso objetivo é **FORMAR O MAIOR BANCO DE DADOS DO MUNDO SOBRE PERGUNTAS E RESPOSTA SOBRE LINGUAGENS DE PROGRAMAÇÃO EM LÍNGUA PORTUGUÊSA.**

Comment: Como parece ter tido alguns problemas em sua experiência aqui. Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) Veja também o nosso [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e faça o nosso [tour](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score -1):

estou impressionado com o SO pt, ele consegue ser pior que a nova versão do Medium. Tive um limite de preguntas atingidos, e além tive diversos votos negativos em uma pergunta, não faz o menor sentido isso. Agora em diante prometo não voltar mais no SO pt, me perdoem por ser iniciante e ter duvidas. E uma outra observação vejo que a comunidade SO pt parece estar ficando "meio morta", muitos perfis (na maioria de iniciantes) que vejo tiveram sua ultima visualização a 5,6 meses atrás, isso é triste.

Comment: Veja se esse [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6544/137387) o ajuda?

Comment: Olá Jss. Sinto por você pensar assim, conheço alguns (pelo menos 3) iniciantes que se propuseram a entender as dicas dada por outros para melhorar suas postagens e hoje estão bem, não estou falando de contas de anos, estou falando de usuários que começaram em Nov/2020 e Dez/2020, ou seja, no máximo 3 meses. O diferencial deles foi aceitar as dicas de onde poderiam melhorar o enunciado de suas perguntas e respostas.

Comment: Como o colega @GuilhermeNascimento mencionou, ser iniciante nunca foi um impeditivo. Aliás, o SOpt é ótimo para iniciantes. Nós temos algumas regras e a comunidade reage muito a elas, mas tenho certeza que se compreender o objeto da comunidade você ficará aqui e entenderá porque existe este filtro.

Comment: Além disso, o SOpt se renova todo dia. Todo mês um usuário bom sai da plataforma e um usuário bom também entra. Isso é cíclico, e também é perseverante em todos tipos de comunidades. É um processo natural entre aceitação e rejeição.