# É incrível a quantidade de deslike que se dá em relação ao stackoverflow em inglês

Tags: suporte, perguntas, stackoverflow

Possuo uma conta no `Stack Overflow` em inglês há alguns anos e notei uma diferença significativa em relação à versão brasileira. Ao observar a quantidade de "dislikes" em qualquer pergunta do fórum, é surpreendente a quantidade de negatividade presente. Parece que cada pergunta é alvo de um "dislike", como se alguns usuários o fizessem como um passatempo diário, sem uma justificativa clara, causando um impacto negativo na `comunidade de programação` em `português`. Essa situação perdura há anos e eu não consigo compreender a `motivação` por trás dos usuários que praticam essa ação. Também é intrigante por que esses usuários ainda não foram removidos ou banidos. Essa situação tem me desestimulado a utilizar a `versão em português` do `Stack Overflow`, levando-me a continuar a utilizar a minha conta original em inglês.

Comment: Se você recebeu muitos votos negativos significa que suas publicações tem muitos problemas. Se você deseja melhorar suas publicações para que elas sejam úteis a comunidade, sirvam como referencias para futuros visitantes e para que você possa obter a ajuda que precisa, então recomendo que entenda a [finalidade do site](/help), depois leia o [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/3635) e o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/3635).

Comment: Note que não existe motivos para banir ninguém, o que pode ocorrer é a suspensão em caso de mau uso do site, ou se não seguir o [código de conduta](/conduct). Publicações de baixa qualidade (fechadas e negativadas) podem causar o veto automático para o autor (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans), o sistema do site percebe que suas publicações tem problemas e irá te barrar até que você as melhore (veja os links do comentário anterior). Estou fechando a pergunta porque ela não é algo que possamos fornecer [meta-tag:suporte], além das orientações dos links.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Por que no stack overflow em português tudo é tão mais negativado?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8266/por-que-no-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas-tudo-%c3%a9-t%c3%a3o-mais-negativado)

Comment: E só pra completar, [no site em inglês também tem muita reclamação](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downvotes), a diferença é que lá o volume diário de perguntas/respostas é muito maior que aqui no SOpt, e por isso vários casos passam desapercebidos pela maioria. Como aqui o volume é menor, fica mais fácil perceber o problema, mas a queda de qualidade (e consequentemente os votos negativos) é um fenômeno geral da rede.

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa foi [movida para um chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147787/), mantidos os os comentários com links úteis, para fácil acesso. Quem quiser acompanhar e/ou participar pode usar o link passado. Importante lembrar que **negativo não é "deslike"** (sic), isso é um equívoco fundamental que pode atrapalhar muito o aproveitamento do sistema. Votos são mera classificação de conteúdo. Negativo indica que precisa editar e melhorar a postagem (quando no escopo). Positivo indica que a comunidade entendeu como útil. É basicamente isso, nada mais.